# Carrierwave: how to get a version of a pdf that only has certain pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, split, carrierwave

In my rails App, I'm using carrierwave. I have a PdfUploader, and in there, I want there to be a version of the pdf with say only the first 3 pages. There's a lot out there on how to get the first page or a particular page as an image, or how to get each page as a separate image, but I want a version of the pdf that has say the first 3 pages together (with the rest of the pdf split off).

Just like how you could make it so this gives you a "thumb" version of the pdf

```
pdf.thumb.url
```

Something like this would be nice

```
pdf.pages([1, 2, 3]).url
```

Would the answer have something to do with using "manipulate!"?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, I think. At the very least, it's a strong step in the right direction. Plop this in pdf_uploader.rb:

```
version :seq_of_imgs do
    process make_seq_of_imgs: [ [1, 2, 3] ]
end

def make_seq_of_imgs(page_arr=[])
    manipulate! do |page, index|
        if page_arr.include?(index+1)
            page
        end
    end
end
```

With that, pdf.seq_of_images.url will give you the first 3 pages of the pdf. Albiet, the quality has been messed with a bit. I'll be looking into this.

Update: I think the Grim gem is also a great help in dealing with pdf pages